# How to imagine a plane defined by Cartesian Plane Equation?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

It isn't difficult for me to imagine a plane based on three points. Also it is quite simple to imagine a plane based on point and normal vector.

Are there some tricks to imagine a plane defined by plane equation $Ax+By+Cz+D=0?$

Comment: The tag "algebraic geometry" doesn't fit.

Comment: You could just find 3 solutions and imagine the plane through those 3 points, or you could find one solution and take $(A, B, C)$ as the normal vector (as Matt suggests below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector $\mathbf{a}=(A,B,C)$ is the normal vector of the plane, and the equation says that the dot product of the normal vector $\mathbf{a}$ and all vectors from the origin to a point on the plane is a constant given by $-D$. Let $\mathbf{x}=(x,y,z)$, then we have:

$$\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{x}=-D$$

If the normal vector $\mathbf{a}$ is normalized to length 1, then $D$ is the distance of the plane from the origin.